# Right clicking for particular layouts PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

I am using PyQt5 and I want to add a right click event for particular layouts within my UI. Is this possible to do?

```
+---------------------+
| right click here    | 
| +-----------------+ |
| | right click here| | each layout
| +-----------------+ | has it\'s own right click event
|                     | 
| +-----------------+ |
| | right click here| |
| +-----------------+ |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: Unless there is a hacky workaround, I believe all mouse events are handled by widgets so you'd need to implement the right click behavior via the widgets in the layouts, not the layouts themselves. From the documentation: "_Mouse events occur when a mouse button is pressed or released inside a widget, or when the mouse cursor is moved._"

Comment: Layouts are elements that handle the distribution policies of the widget in the window, that is, they are elements of logic, they are not graphic elements!!!.